# The loud speaker on my Samsung Captivate stopped working! Is my phone broken or can I fix it myself?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, speaker

The speaker at the back of my phone, used for ringing and playing sound without headphones, is completely silent. Do I need to have it repaired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Samsung Captivate's speaker can work its way loose, usually after the phone takes a hard knock (like being dropped). In most cases you can fix it yourself by opening the back and pressing HARD on the speaker with your thumb. You should probably power the phone off to do this.

Comment: Oh man! Didn't think it was going to work but it did! Thanks a lot for the TIP. If it was my question I would have accepted this as the answer! :-) Thanks for the question & the answer!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're up to fixing it yourself. Here are TechRepublic teardown links in case you need them. Just make sure you have the proper tools (and patience). Good luck!

[TechRepublic Teardown - Main](http://content.techrepublic.com.com/2346-13625_11-456848.html)

[Speaker Assembly - Front](http://content.techrepublic.com.com/2346-13625_11-456848-44.html?tag=content;leftCol)